# my updatevalue function is not working when I click on remove butt

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

I dont know why the sum is not get update when I click on remove button after adding some value in input because when I input some value, it updates sum but when I remove, value becomes zero cause of remove_item function but doesnt update the sum. thank you so much for giving some time to my problem in advance.

```js
function updatevalue(item, value, data) {
  var td = item.parentNode.nextElementSibling;
  var div = item.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
  var onupdate = 0;
  if (value) {
    onupdate = data * value;
  } else if (value === 0) {
    onupdate = data * 0;
  } else {
    onupdate = data * 0;
  }
  td.innerHTML = onupdate;
  var totalValues = document.querySelectorAll(".int-input");
  var total = 0;
  totalValues.forEach((k) => {
    total += parseInt(k.innerHTML);
  });
  div.querySelector('.total').innerHTML = total
}

function add_item(item, next) {
  item.parentNode.style.display = "none";
  next.style.display = "block";
  item.parentNode.nextSibling.nextSibling.nextSibling.nextSibling.firstChild.value = '';
  item.parentNode.nextSibling.nextSibling.nextSibling.nextSibling.firstChild.disabled = false;
}

function remove_item(item, prev) {
  item.parentNode.nextSibling.nextSibling.firstChild.disabled = true;
  item.parentNode.nextSibling.nextSibling.firstChild.value = '0';
  item.parentNode.nextSibling.nextSibling.nextSibling.nextSibling.innerHTML = '0';
  item.parentNode.style.display = "none";
  prev.style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h2>Div1</h2>
  <table>
    <th>Select</th>
    <th>Intake</th>
    <th>Total</th>
    <tr>
      <td><input id="btn" type="button" value="Add" name="{{a.Food}}" onclick="add_item(this, this.parentNode.nextSibling.nextSibling)"></td>
      <td style="display: none;text-align: center;"><input id="btn" type="button" name="{{a.Food}}" value="Remove" onclick="remove_item(this,this.parentNode.previousElementSibling)"></td>
      <td><input type="Number" name="some" id="{{a.Food}}" value="0" oninput="updatevalue(this,this.value,9)" disabled></td>
      <td class="int-input">0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>the sum of this div table </td>
      <td class="total">0</td>
      <td>sum</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<div>
  <h2>div2</h2>
  <table>
    <th>Select</th>
    <th>Intake</th>
    <th>Total</th>
    <tr>
      <td><input id="btn" type="button" value="Add" name="{{a.Food}}" onclick="add_item(this, this.parentNode.nextSibling.nextSibling)"></td>
      <td style="display: none;text-align: center;"><input id="btn" type="button" name="{{a.Food}}" value="Remove" onclick="remove_item(this,this.parentNode.previousElementSibling)"></td>
      <td><input type="Number" name="some" id="{{a.Food}}" value="0" oninput="updatevalue(this,this.value,9)" disabled></td>
      <td class="int-input">0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>the sum of this div table </td>
      <td class="total">0</td>
      <td>sum</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: It's not a good practice to stack `.nextSibling` your way in order to select another element. Imagine having table with many columns, you would not want to use `.nextSibling` multiple times until you reach the target element.

If your `<td>` has **id/class**, you can use `.querySelector()` to select elements with specified selectors. I've modified your code, see sample snippet below:

```js
//https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68965719/my-updatevalue-function-is-not-working-when-i-click-on-remove-butt/68966136

function updatevalue(item, value, data) {
  var td = item.parentNode.nextElementSibling;
  var div = item.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
  var onupdate = 0;
  if (value) {
    onupdate = data * value;
  } else if (value === 0) {
    onupdate = data * 0;
  } else {
    onupdate = data * 0;
  }
  td.innerHTML = onupdate;
  var totalValues = div.querySelectorAll(".int-input");
  var total = 0;
  totalValues.forEach((k) => {
    total += parseInt(k.innerHTML);
  });
  div.querySelector('.total').innerHTML = total
}

function add_item(item) {
  var tr = item.parentElement.parentElement;
  
  var add = tr.querySelector('.addtd');
  add.style.display = "none";
  
  var remove = tr.querySelector('.removetd');
  remove.style.display = "block";
  
  var input = item.parentElement.parentElement.querySelector('.intake');
  input.value = "";
  input.disabled = false;
}

function remove_item(item,data) {
  var tr = item.parentElement.parentElement;
  var table = item.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement;
  
  var add = tr.querySelector('.addtd');
  add.style.display = "block";
  
  var remove = tr.querySelector('.removetd');
  remove.style.display = "none";
  
  var input = tr.querySelector('.intake');
  input.value = "0";
  input.disabled = true;
  
  var total = tr.querySelector('.int-input');
  total.innerHTML= "0"; 
  
  // Loop through table to get sum
  var sumvalue = 0;
  var subtotal = table.querySelectorAll('.int-input');
 
  subtotal.forEach((k) => {
    sumvalue += parseInt(k.innerHTML);
  });
 
  var sum = table.querySelector('.total');
  sum.innerHTML= sumvalue;
}
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h2>Div1</h2>
  <table>
    <th>Select</th>
    <th>Intake</th>
    <th>Total</th>
    <tr>
      <td class="addtd"><input id="btn" type="button" value="Add" name="{{a.Food}}" onclick="add_item(this)"></td>
      <td style="display: none;text-align: center;" class="removetd"><input id="btn" type="button" name="{{a.Food}}" value="Remove" onclick="remove_item(this,this.parentNode.previousElementSibling)"></td>
      <td><input type="Number" name="some" class="intake" id="{{a.Food}}" value="0" oninput="updatevalue(this,this.value,9)" disabled></td>
      <td class="int-input">0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="addtd"><input id="btn" type="button" value="Add" name="{{a.Food}}" onclick="add_item(this)"></td>
      <td style="display: none;text-align: center;" class="removetd"><input id="btn" type="button" name="{{a.Food}}" value="Remove" onclick="remove_item(this)"></td>
      <td><input type="Number" name="some" class="intake" id="{{a.Food}}" value="0" oninput="updatevalue(this,this.value,9)" disabled></td>
      <td class="int-input">0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>the sum of this div table </td>
      <td class="total">0</td>
      <td>sum</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<div>
  <h2>div2</h2>
  <table>
    <th>Select</th>
    <th>Intake</th>
    <th>Total</th>
    <tr>
      <td class="addtd"><input id="btn" type="button" value="Add" name="{{a.Food}}" onclick="add_item(this)"></td>
      <td style="display: none;text-align: center;" class="removetd"><input id="btn" type="button" name="{{a.Food}}" value="Remove" onclick="remove_item(this)"></td>
      <td><input type="Number" name="some" class="intake" id="{{a.Food}}" value="0" oninput="updatevalue(this,this.value,9)" disabled></td>
      <td class="int-input">0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="addtd"><input id="btn" type="button" value="Add" name="{{a.Food}}" onclick="add_item(this)"></td>
      <td style="display: none;text-align: center;" class="removetd"><input id="btn" type="button" name="{{a.Food}}" value="Remove" onclick="remove_item(this)"></td>
      <td><input type="Number" name="some" class="intake" id="{{a.Food}}" value="0" oninput="updatevalue(this,this.value,9)" disabled></td>
      <td class="int-input">0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>the sum of this div table </td>
      <td class="total">0</td>
      <td>sum</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: can you plz elaborate your Note why is this not good practice So in future I will be careful

Comment: Thanks bro but sorry I cant explain you perfectly. In this whenever I remove , the sum gets zero, but dont know how to remove the total value from sum. Because sum is the sum of every total value in one table.  In actual I have many tr in table not only one.

Comment: I understand, you should've mentioned it earlier :) I've edited the 2nd code snippet. Everytime remove button is clicked, using `querySelectorAll`, we loop through each row and add the value of `.int-input` to get the new total, finally update that value to `.total`. **Beware** that in your updatevalue, you are using `document.querySelectorAll` so it will update the total in **all** divs in the document.

Comment: one thing is that any way to call the updatevalue function when total value gets zero because only in this situation the sum is not updating

Comment: yes you are right i havent right line there in actuall it is  div.querySelectorAll(".int-input");

Comment: Okay I've edited it to the snippet. Sorry I didn't really understand the last one, in which case the sum is not updating? Did you test the 2nd snippet below?

Comment: div.querySelectorAll(".int-input");         the div variable is replaced with document in updatevalue function. and the snippet is working perfectly thank you bro many blessings from india to you  :)

Comment: oninput="updatevalue(this,this.value,9)" is the right way to call this function in the Input Tag

Comment: or any other suggestion to write all the code in efficient way

Comment: It's fine actually, but if you want to reduce function parameter/argument, updatevalue(this,9) is enough. Since you can get `this.value` inside the function. Does it answer your question? Don't forget to accept it as answer if it solved your problem. Let me know if you have another question.

Comment: no questions. nice learning from you. thanks again :). and also I like your attitude. And can you plz suggest me about carrier or coding cause I m doing B.E. in IT. and in final year.